# How to design a generic callback url with params?

Tags: regex, generics, schema

I have a service which allows client to create a callback url and my service will use that url to call a 3rd party website. The url pattern that the clients provide would be different. The url contains params of student_id and age.
Assume that the client save a url in my service as

```
https://www.client1.com/student/{student_id}:{age}
```

My service will call the url with

```
https://www.client1.com/student/12345:18
```

or, if the url provided is

```
https://www.client2.com/update?student_id={student_id}&age={age}
```

My service will call

```
https://www.client2.com/update?student_id=12345&age=18
```

I want to support multiple student_id and age, how should I make the url more generic? Such as, how to define a pattern/schema that represent repeating pair of params? I think some urls that need to be supported would be like

```
https://www.client.com/update?00001:18,00002:15,00003:17 

https://www.client.com/update?students=00001,00002,00003&age=18,15,17
```

(where 00001-00003 are studentids, 18,15,17 are ages)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex question, rather an API schema question.

To support repeating patterns of various formats you can define a `{repeat}...{/repeat}` schema, or a `{start_repeat}...{end_repeat}` schema. Using your examples:

Client 1 API example:

```
https://www.client1.com/update?students=00001,00002,00003&age=18,15,17
```

Client 1 API schema:

```
https://www.client1.com/update?students={repeat}{student_id}{/repeat}&age={repeat}{age}{/repeat}
```

Client 2 API example:

```
https://www.client2.com/update?00001:18,00002:15,00003:17
```

Client 2 API schema:

```
https://www.client2.com/update?{repeat}{student_id}:{age}{/repeat}
```

Then, to compose the URL on your end, you globally extract `{repeat}` ... `{/repeat}`, and for each repeat, loop through your students, resolving `{student_id}` and `{age}`.

This repeat schema assumes a `,` separator. If your clients have different separators, you could enhance the schema with `{comma_repeat}...{/comma_repeat}`, `{semicolon_repeat}...{/semicolon_repeat}`. Alternatively, keep the repeat schema as is, and introduce a `{repeat_separator};{/repeat_separator}` that should preceded any `{repeat}...{/repeat}` patterns.

Comment: @Cheuk Lun Ho: Any question? Does this adress your needs?

Comment: @Cheuk Lun Ho: Care to accept the answer? Help goes both ways.